# Trying to do an array within an array in animate CC (html5 canvas)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, animate-cc

```
var Home = this;
creategame();
var beasts = [];
function creategame() {
for (i=0;i<4;i++)
{

beasts[i][0] = "lib.ojb"+i.toString()+"()";
beasts[i][1] = 150+(i*125);
}

for (i=0;i<4;i++)
{
var n = new beasts[0][0][0];
    n.x = beasts[i][1];
    n.y = 350;
    n.name = "animal"+i.toString();
    stage.addChild(n);
    n.addEventListener("pressmove", dragFunc);
    n.addEventListener("pressup",release);

}
}
```

Is it impossible to write the array as 'var beasts' and then expect the software to create the subarrays when told 'beasts[i][0]=something' resulting in it putting beasts = [[something,[]]] basically? the console keeps telling me **'cannot read property of undefined'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an array for the beasts items. You can't assign property values to something that doesn't exist.

```
for (i=0;i<4;i++){
    beasts[i] = [];
    beasts[i][0] = "lib.ojb"+i.toString()+"()";
    beasts[i][1] = 150+(i*125);
}
```

Edit: here is another way to write it.

```
for (i=0;i<4;i++){
    beasts[i] = [
        "lib.ojb"+i.toString()+"()",
        150+(i*125)
    ];
}
```

Comment: didn't I do it by saying `var beasts = [];` at the start?

Comment: That is defining the array of beasts. You need to also define each beast as an array (or object)

Comment: so basically I have to write `var beasts = [[animal1],[animal2], etc] ` otherwise it won't work? and what if I just write `var beasts = [[],[],[],[]]` will it know how to work with that?

Comment: Well, you benefit from instantiating the beast array in the for loop because it allows you to change a single number to add more beasts.